# Extracting Lon and Lat range of a grib file

Tags: python, grib

I am pretty new to the GRIB format but I currently need to deal with it. Using wgrib, I managed to extract the fields I wanted, corresponding times, etc ..

But I miss the coordinates of the points of th grid, or the latitude and longitude range of the grid.

How can I get that ?
I would prefer using only python and wgrib but if there is any other simple way please let me know !
What I've found on the web seems to mainly concern wgrib2 format.

Comment: So do you want to use wgrib or pure python? In the latter case, using `pygrib` might be easier.

Comment: I would prefer to use wgrid if possible. What would you recommend ?

Comment: Can you provide an example on how you use wgrib with python?

Comment: I just use `os.system()`.

Comment: Are you on windows platform?

Comment: No, I'm on a linux system.

Comment: on linux, using pygrib is very easy and lat/lon are available as an attribute for each grib message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in comments you have to use module `pygrib`.

I post a sample code to get lat and lon arrays from all messages of a grib file by method `latlons`. After extracting I convert data to numpy arrays:

```
import pygrib
import numpy as np

grib = pygrib.open('test.grib')
for g in grib:
    lt, ln = g.latlons() # lt - latitude, ln - longitude
    lt, ln = np.array(lt), np.array(ln)
    print (lt, ln)
```

Comment: It sounds simple. I have questions. How to pull the parameters or variable using the command style?. How to get to know the time if dataset subject to forecast dataset